# String comparison in java

Tags: java

I take a string from an array that stores strings. Then I print it for check and see that is this that i want. When I compare it with the string that it suppose to be I get error.
When I print bString it is "root"!!! When I compare it is not!

```
System.out.println(aString);
if (aString.equals("root")) {
  System.out.println("its ok!");
}
```

Comment: you are printing `aString` and comparing `bString`.

Comment: print `bString` not `aString`.

Comment: Well yes here you have a point! But still after that is not working!

Comment: Post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), then...

Comment: When you say you get an error, what happens? Do you mean it just doesn't print `its ok!`. Check that there are no leading or trailing spaces in `aString`.

Comment: Try printing it as this: `System.out.printf("[%s]%n", bString);` and what you get. I suspect there is some EOL or whitespace after `root` in `bString`

Answer (score 1):

You may have whitespace characters. trim it.

```
System.out.println(aString + " => " + aString.length()); 
if (aString.trim().equals("root")) {   
    System.out.println("its ok!"); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try trim() and equalsIgnoreCase(). For equal() return true both string must be identical (no white space or case differences).